# Trying to Expand and Center a Div with two divs on Each Side

Tags: html, css

I have the following div structure below:

```
<div class="Large-Centered-Div">
<div class="Left-Div">
    <div class="Inner-Left-Div">
    </div>
    <div class="Inner-Center-Div">
    </div>
    <div class="Inner-Right-Div">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Center-Div">
    (Small Image/Etc. Would Go Here)
</div>
<div class="Right-Div">
    <div class="Inner-Left-Div">
    </div>
    <div class="Inner-Center-Div">
    </div>
    <div class="Inner-Right-Div">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am looking to do is a bit complicated, but hopefully this all makes sense:

1. Have the "Large-Centered-Div" expand the entire width of the page and within the "Large-Centered-Div" have the "Left-Div", "Center-Div", and "Right-Div" set up so that the "Center-Div" is small and the "Left-Div" and "Right-Div" be large such that the "Center-Div" is small in width but in the middle.
2. Within both the "Left-Div" and "Right-Div" I would like the "Inner-Center-Div" to take up the majority of the space and only have the "Inner-Left-Div" and "Inner-Right-Div" take up enough space to show an image for their respective edges. In addition, I would like the "Inner-Center-Div" to be fluid with the width size.

With these things in mind, I have achieved the first goal on my list but not the second. Here is the code for the first item:

```
    .Large-Centered-Div {
        position:relative;
        left:0px;
        right:0px;
    }

    .Left-Div {
        float:left;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:47%;
    }

    .Center-Div {
        float:left;
        width:6%;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .Right-Div {
        float:left;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:47%;
    }
```

The question is, how do I achieve #2? Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean 'I would like the "Inner-Center-Div" to be fluid with the width size.'?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the inner left and inner right div auto for the image and making the inter center div a certain percentage.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is hard code the width of the image. let's call it w pixels. So:

```
.Inner-Left-Div, .Inner-Right-Div { width: wpx; }
```

Then the inner center div will expand to fill the rest of the space.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make the div's width a function of percent, that way, they will always be the same relative to each other, and they will resize perfectly.

`.Large-Centered-Div{
  width: 100%;
}

.Left-Div, .Right-Div, .Inner-Left-Div, .Inner-Right-Div{
  width: 40%;
}

.Center-Div, .Inner-Center-Div{
  width:20%;
}`

This is by far the fastest and most DRY way of accomplishing this.

also, for convention's sake, it would be better to leave your class names lowercase. It's easier to remember your conventions if you simplify them, good luck!

-Brian